# Hot-hot systems and its effect on RPO/RTO

Tags: networking, hosting

How is hot-hot or live-live system related with RPO and/or RTO?

I want to understand what exactly a hot-hot system means? Is it really achievable? How does it affect the RPO and RTO?

[Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117050/live-live-system-and-rpo-rto) of the question on stackoverflow which recommended to post the question on this forum.

**Note**: [Here's a link](http://www.corexchange.com/blog/disaster-recovery-hot-warm-cold-sites-key-differences) for hot/live and cold environments.
[Here's one](http://www.druva.com/blog/understanding-rpo-and-rto) for RPO and RTO. Let me know if I should elaborate on any other terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: live live (hot hot, always on, whatever you prefer for the same concept) has no rpo or rto, or it can be declared as zero. You are live live! For what reason would you determine a recovery point or a recovery time? If one system fails, the other (live) one is able to assume immediately, instantaneously, without your client een perceive the switch! Warm standby is another concept, very different approach, and yes, it requires you to determine for your customers that if one system fails at 11:00 a.m, you'll definitely able to recover it to the same state (app, db transactions, etc) as it was 30 mins before, or 10:30a.m. (your rpo).. and this job will require 3h(rto) of your hardworking as sysadmin. So everyone will be happy at 2p.m. understood? Thank you.